# Oldstyle numerals by default with Lucida Bright T1

Tags: oldstylenums, lucida

I bought the Lucida fonts from TUG. Is it possible to use the T1 version and have old style figures in text **by default** (that is, without the need of selecting them with `\oldstylenums` each time?

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\usepackage{textcomp}               % necessary for \oldstylenums to work
\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{hlh}{1} % necessary for \oldstylenums to work 
\begin{document}
1234567890                % these are lining
\oldstylenums{1234567890} % these are osf
\end{document}
```

For example, in the code above `textcomp` and `\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{hlh}{1}` are necessary for `\oldstylenums` to work, as `lucidabr`'s documentation indicates. But I would like to have oldstyle numerals by default throughout the text, instead of having to select them on an individual basis as in the snippet above.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal document to show how you load the Lucida Bright fonts?

Comment: Done, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lucidabr` package has no option for choosing oldstyle numbers by default, but you can do it manually.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{hlhj}% normally hlh

\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

[image]